# Struts, email validation in ActionForm validate ()

Tags: validation, struts

I have page that contains email input. My goal is to make validation on the server side. 
Right now my validation code is as follows:

```
public ActionErrors validate(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request) {

        ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();

            if(this.name == null || this.name.trim().equals(""))
                errors.add("name", new ActionMessage("errors.required","Name"));
            if(this.email == null || this.email.trim().equals(""))
                errors.add("email", new ActionMessage("errors.required","Email"));
            if(this.city == null || this.city.trim().equals(""))
                errors.add("city", new ActionMessage("errors.required","City"));           
               if(this.country == null || this.country.trim().equals(""))
                errors.add("country", new ActionMessage("errors.required","Country")); 
                return errors;   
    }
```

I know i can make email validation using Regular Expressions within validate method. Is there any different way to validate fields like email, ip etc within validate method that is provided by Struts? But with the restriction that validation must be strictly in validate method. Thanks

Comment: Unrelated, but I'd really consider using something like `StringUtils.isBlank(xyz)` or writing your own to avoid a lot of noisy, pointless duplication.

Answer (score 0):

[commons-validator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/) may help you to achieve what you are trying to do.

To validate:

- emails: `org.apache.commons.validator.EmailValidator`
- ip: `org.apache.commons.validator.routines.InetAddressValidator`
- ...